# Why does this statement introduce memory?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm learning SystemVerilog and today my lecturer warned us against accidentally introducing memory into combinational systems. He used the following code as an example of this:

```
module gate(output logic y, input logic a);
       always_comb
          if(a)
             y = '1;
endmodule
```

However, I don't understand why this presents a problem. As far as I can see, this is just a simple buffer. In what way does this code introduce memory into the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the beginning of the simulation if `a == 0` the value of `y` will be `'0`. If later `a == 1'b1` then `y` will become `'1`. What value do you expect `y` to have when later on `a == 0`?

The answer to this question is that it will retain its previous value: `'1`. That is *not* the behaviour of *combinational logic*, whose output by definition only depends on the current state of the inputs, *not* on their previous states. In order to implement the behaviour you have described, the synthesiser will need a component with *state*, with *storage*, with *memory*. It will fulfill this by using a *latch*.

Comment: So, would this be fixed by adding `else y = '0;` after the if statement?

Comment: Don't expect a buffer to be synthesised after adding your `else` branch. Whether a buffer is required or not depends on the electrical and timing constraints, not on the boolean behaviour. I suspect your `always` block will be optimised away to nothing.